# LINQ Syntax for Selecting a Parameter to Be Copied

Tags: c#, wpf, linq

I have a some code to sort my collection in linq in C#. I want it to group by the houseName to sum over the volumes, order that collection, but also pass a third parameter, pctVol, to the new sorted collection. What am I doing wrong? I know that the problem lies in the pctVol = group.Selecct(item => item.pctVol) line.

```
            var inBetween = this.GroupBy(item => item.houseName)
             .Select(group =>
                    new DataItem
                    {
                        houseName = group.Key,
                        VOLUME = group.Sum(item => item.VOLUME),
                        pctVol = group.Select(item => item.pctVol)
                    })
             .ToList();
            ObservableCollection<DataItem> objSort = new ObservableCollection<DataItem>(inBetween.OrderBy(DataItem =>
                                    DataItem.VOLUME));
            return objSort;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What kind of value do you want pctVol to have? With that code, it looks like DataItem.pctVol will be an IEnumerable containing all the pctVol values in that group.

If you want a single value, and all the pctVol values in each group are guaranteed to be the same, then you could just take the value from the first element, like this: pctVol = group.First().pctVol

Comment: Doh! That makes sense. Thanks!